# How can you improve a 50GB table?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

We currently use InnoDB storage engine and are getting approximately 1k/s. Once the record is inserted into the database it gets queried in reports and that's where the problem is. We have added the right indexes and compressed the table, but it only helps so much.

Mostly only the first 30 days of records get queried hard, the rest don't get access as much. Records more than one year old don't get queried at all really. Also, our users only really access the latest data/records.

Would Mysql's partitioning feature be ideal for us? would we have to implement our own partitioning via our application?

Comment: Yes, in your scenario, you should partition the table based on the created date..

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL query cache can considerably improve the performance of SELECT queries.  If you are not already using it then you could definitely benefit from it and it maybe easier to implement than partitioning.

Query cache stores the results of SELECT queries in memory, and uses them to provide an instant response if the same SELECT query is sent to the server again before the table changes.

Here is an example of the my.ini configuration items needed to allocate 2GB of the server's memory to cache SELECT queries:

```
#Query Cache
query_cache_size = 209715200
query_cache_limit = 10485740
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't apply to innoDB. I'm also aware of the innodb buffer pool, but the problem lies in the actual table size.

Comment: I use innoDb tables in MySQL and the query cache works great. Perhaps I am misunderstanding. Sorry I couldn't help!